# J2ME very light AES/RSA implementation

Tags: encryption, java-me, rsa, aes

I have a problem when attempting to implement AES/RSA encryption on J2ME,
that problem being that bouncycastle (a library that supports java and specially J2ME) is too big for implementation on a mobile phone solution (about 860 classes in total without the test and example classes).

I've googled around and the only alternative I can really find is JCE... which in itself is also too big.

Does anyone here know a way to implement it in a very small solution? Or a "tiny" library that I can use? (like for instance for TEA: http://www.winterwell.com/software/TEA.php)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022183/bouncycastle-encryption-algorithms-not-provided for some possible ideas.

Comment: How about having a look into http://www.bebbosoft.de/java/minissl/index.wiki? It might be lightweight enough for J2ME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to do a little work you should be able to take the Bouncycastle J2ME source code as a starting point and with judicious use of copy and paste implement just RSA and AES very compactly.

UPDATE:

Just as an exercise I tried this myself. It took about 45 minutes of copying and light editing to produce 27 Bouncycastle classes that completely implemented AESEngine and RSAEngine exactly as they are in Bouncycastle J2ME sources. But I did no testing of them at all, namely because I don't really understand what to do with my Netbeans J2ME project that I created them in.

Comment: Or rather: Remove everything from Bouncycastle which is not needed.

Comment: Do you have RSA example of bouncycastle on j2me?

Answer (score 1):

How about you try the lightweight API version? Go to [Bouncy Castle's latest release page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and download the J2ME build. Its just about 7MB - much lighter in size.